# `generateblocks` method not found, when called via json-rpc

Tags: monerod, rpc

I am using Moner (`Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.1.2-release)`) on ubuntu. I am running a regtest with this .conf file and these command line flags:

**bitmonero.conf**.

```
# /etc/monero/monerod.conf
#custom
sync-pruned-blocks=1
prune-blockchain=1
enable-dns-blocklist=1
no-zmq=1

# Data directory (blockchain db and indices)
data-dir=/root/monero/.monero  # Remember to create the monero user first

# Log file
log-file=/root/monero/monerod.log
max-log-file-size=0            # Prevent monerod from managing the log files; we want logrotate to take care of that

# P2P full node
p2p-bind-ip=0.0.0.0            # Bind to all interfaces (the default)
p2p-bind-port=18080            # Bind to default port

# RPC open node
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0            # Bind to all interfaces
rpc-bind-port=18081            # Bind on default port
confirm-external-bind=1        # Open node (confirm)
restricted-rpc=1               # Prevent unsafe RPC calls
no-igd=1                       # Disable UPnP port mapping

# Slow but reliable db writes
db-sync-mode=safe

# Emergency checkpoints set by MoneroPulse operators will be enforced to workaround potential consensus bugs
# Check https://monerodocs.org/infrastructure/monero-pulse/ for explanation and trade-offs
enforce-dns-checkpointing=1

out-peers=64              # This will enable much faster sync and tx awareness; the default 8 is suboptimal nowadays
in-peers=1024             # The default is unlimited; we prefer to put a cap on this

limit-rate-up=1048576     # 1048576 kB/s == 1GB/s; a raise from default 2048 kB/s; contribute more to p2p network
limit-rate-down=1048576   # 1048576 kB/s == 1GB/s; a raise from default 8192 kB/s; allow for faster initial sync
```

**Command Line Arguments**
`/monerod --config-file=./bitmonero.conf --regtest --keep-fakechain --offline --fixed-difficulty 1 --detach`

Now; other rpc methods like `get_block_count` is working and I am getting a valid response. But when I try to run `generateblocks`, it says `Method not found`.

**Example**
*Request:*

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": "0",
    "method": "generateblocks",
    "params": {
        "amount_of_blocks": 1,
        "wallet_address": "46brz8wwWzcLh77u8tVjeM4SpdnGRy8xeBXCEiMUgwBkeKBCierr2UPDFMDiL7ieSMGnuqDvkaoXb2x3PW5e9KkT1QdTwKD",
        "starting_nonce": 0
    }
}
```

*Response:*

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": -32601,
        "message": "Method not found"
    },
    "id": "0",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generateblocks` isn't made available if you are running restricted (which you are, as you have `restricted-rpc=1` in your config).

Comment: The `generateblocks` is now working and the `get_block_count` is also increasing. But the problem is; I am not getting the coinbase reward on the address i have provided to the `generateblocks`.

Comment: "I am not getting the coinbase reward" <- coinbase rewards aren't available (unlocked) until the block is matured (i.e. is >60 blocks deep).